# He...his boss that he...back after his vacation. Which answer fits the blank?

Tags: future-tense

I am interested in this sentence:

> **He ______ his boss that he ______ back after his vacation.**
>
> **a) doesn't tell / hasn't come**
>
> **b) won't tell / won't have come**
>
> **c) isn't telling / doesn't come**
>
> **d) hasn't told / won't be coming**
>
> **e) didn't tell / hadn't come**

I've answered **B** but it's obvious that we can't have a sentence with two auxiliary verbs "to be" in the future form. But the right answer is **D** and I'm curious about the secont part. Since **won't be coming** is the future continuous tense I find no way of implementing it in this sentence, Am I mistaken? What way of usage the future continuous is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d) is the answer. 'won't be coming' is the same as 'isn't going to come back' or  'isn't coming back' - something planned.

Comment: Ah I forgot that the future continuous could be used for future plans, i.e something that was arranged. Thx, it is an easy question

Comment: `hasn't told` is because, you were expecting which something has been done but it's not happened right?

Comment: @TMoraes  Right. He hasn't told the boss yet, and the vacation isn't over yet.